# Ruby: Replacing bullets pasted from MS Word

Tags: ascii, special-characters

I need to remove bullet symbols from text pasted from MS Word, but I can't figure out what to match on.

When printed to STDOUT the symbol displays as â¢
The ascii codes for these characters are 194 and 162.
The ascii code for • symbols is 149

Any suggestions how to proceed either in JavaScript or Ruby code?

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, you should be able to use something like:

`mystring.gsub(/[\xxx]/,'whatever')`

where `xxx` is the character code you are looking for. You can see what that code is by just doing a `puts mystring` in irb and it should show you

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with the bullet points, including getting the symbols you describe. I tried a variety of regEx filters and couldn't get anything to work, either on the bullet point or those resulting â ¢ characters.

However, I did manage to find a way to filter the bullet point (or any similar character) using a custom method. It's not pretty or ideal, but it works:

```
def strip_bullet_point(value) 
  first_char = 0
  value.each_char { |c| c =~ /[A-Za-z]/ ? break : first_char += 1 }

  value[first_char...value.length]
end
```

This will also remove all preceding blanks and other non alphabet characters, since they also return nil for the =~ check.

Do not use `/[[:alpha:]]/` for the expression match, as that will consider the  â ¢ characters as letters. Just note that `/[A-Za-z]/` will give false negatives for non-English characters, such as 'ñ'.